# Pass variable from sheet to module? VBA

Tags: excel, vba, variables

I was passing variable to another sub using following code. it works fine if both subs resides in same place . now i moved my "Selectsheet" sub to module 1. now i dont know how to pass my variable. any idea?

```
Selectsheet X:="B6"
```

Thanks

Comment: Is your Sub declared as `Public`?

Comment: Selectsheet sub is private

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your Sub Declaration to Public

```
Public Sub SelectSheet(X as String)
```

You can't access private subs from different modules.